# Importance Sampling - By Hand Calculation and Example

Tags: distributions, sampling, bootstrap, monte-carlo, importance-sampling

To understand Importance sampling, I did a little experiment as described here. Since I'm getting high deviations when proposal distribution is not uniform, I would like to know if my steps are correct.

1. Generated 20 samples from a biased dice with pmf as: P(X=1)=0.4, P(X=2)=0.3, P(X=3)=0.15, P(X=4)=0.05,P(X=5)=0.05, P(X=6)=0.05. The samples are:S=  (1,1,2,2,2, 1,1,1,5,3, 2,1,5,3,6, 2,2,1,1,1)
2. Calculated theoretical  E(X)=1x0.40+2x0.30+...+6x0.05 = 2.20. The E(X) for the sample is: (1+1+2+...+1+1+1)/20 = 2.15 (which I deem close enough to the theoretical E(X) of 2.20.

*AT THIS POINT I PRETEND I DON'T KNOW THE PMF OF X USED IN GENERATING THE SAMPLE S. SO, I USE IMPORTANCE SAMPLING TO GET AN ESTIMATE OF X, THE FACE VALUE OF A DIE THROW.*

3. If I consider the proposal distribution is uniform, and sample, say 10 points, uniformly from S, I notice the expectation is close to original i.e. 2.15. In fact, I got S2={2(11), 1(18), 2(4), 1(20), 5(13), 1(1), 1(12), 1(1), 5(9), 5(13) }. The numbers enclosed by the braces indicates the actual random number got from uniformly sampling from 1,2,..,20. e.g 2(11) indicates, we got random number 11, and 2 is the element at the 11th position in the original sample S. Finally, E(X) for this S2 is: (2+1+..+5+5)/10=2.4
4. Now I repeat #3, but using a different pmf (shown below) instead of uniform.
   P(Y=1)=P(Y=2)=P(Y=3)=P(Y=4)=0.20, P(Y=20)=0.05, P(Y=y)=0.01 for y=5,6,..,19

   4a. One such sample generated is  S3=(2(4), 1(2), 2(4), 1(2), 2(3), 2(11), 3(10), 2(4), 2(3), 1(2) )
   E(X) on S3 = (0.2x2 +  0.2x1  +  0.2x2  +  0.2x1  +
   0.2x2  +  0.01x2  + 0.01x3 +  0.2x2 +  0.2x2 + 0.2x1)/ (0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.2+0.01+0.01+0.20+0.20+0.20) 
   = 2.65 / 3.61 
   = 0.7340 (this is way too far from 2.15 or theoretical 2.20)

**My questions:**
Are the ways of getting samples as in step-4, and calculating E(X) in step-4a correct? If not, pls help me understand what I'm missing out?

Comment: Step 3 is a form of bootstrap, not importance sampling. You cannot implement importance sampling without computing the ratio true probability/importance probability, so I am unsure which form of importance sampling you are seeking.

Comment: @ Xi'an - I couldn't get my head around the fact that to calculate f(x)/g(x) where f(x) and g(x) are the original and the proposal distribution, we must know f(x). And, in that case, why don't we evaluate E(x) directly!
Further, I always thought, we can design g(x) to emulate a uniform distribution, and thus bootstrap can be viewed as a special case of importance sampling!
At any rate, I'm learning, and appreciate your further feedback.